# What is the use of Hbernate IN keyword before where clause

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpql

Some where in my project I found the below Syntax

```
createQuery("select stuInfo from StudentInfo stuInfo, IN(stuInfo.studentList) studentList "
    + "where stuInfo.completed =:completed and studentList.Date is null");
```

I tried to Google it  what is the use of **IN** keyword before where clause, But I didn't find any explanation regard this concept.

Comment: Do you have any proof it's legal HQL syntax?

Comment: I cant provide you any proof but I can say this query is working in my projects from last 2 year, During debug I found this.

Comment: And what is the type of `StudentInfo.studentList`?

Comment: Check sql that it produce

Comment: studentList is another table,Mapped with StudentInfo as @OneToMany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked it, it's just a shorthand for an INNER JOIN, in your case

```
select stuInfo from StudentInfo stuInfo inner join stuInfo.studentList studentList ...
```

where actually it's more meaningful to use the alias `student`, not `studentList`, because that's what you refer to by it.